# How do I use OpenGL to make spritesheet animation?

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, sprite-sheet

I have a spritesheet consisting of 8 sprites, each of which is a frame in an animation. I have written shaders to display the first frame of the animation with OpenGL, but I do not know how to switch to the second frame.

Comment: Simplest way is for the CPU code to do it - draw a different sprite each frame

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the sprites with a fragment shader by texture sampling. Say your `spritesheet` consists of `8 * 6` sprites (2D spritesheet), each sprite can be extracted as follows.

```c
#version 400 core

in vec2 v_uvs;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_time; // sec

out vec4 fragColor;

const float SPRITE_COLUMNS = 8.0;
const float SPRITE_ROWS = 6.0;
const uint NUM_OF_SPRITES = 48;

void main(void) {
    uint sprite_idx = int(u_time * 20) % NUM_OF_SPRITES;
    vec2 pos = vec2(sprite_idx % int(SPRITE_COLUMNS), int(sprite_idx / SPRITE_COLUMNS));
    fragColor = texture(u_texture, vec2((v_uvs.x / SPRITE_COLUMNS) + pos.x * (1.0 / SPRITE_COLUMNS),
        (v_uvs.y / SPRITE_ROWS) + pos.y * (1.0 / SPRITE_ROWS)));
}
```